# Blank image is coming when I try to get image from EAGLView using snapshot method

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, ios6, eaglview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is glReadPixels() failing in this code in iOS 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528365/why-is-glreadpixels-failing-in-this-code-in-ios-6-0)

Blank image is coming when I try to get image from EAGLView using snapshot method in iOS 6. How can I fix this issue?

Here is the reference link for snapshot method:
[How do I take a snapshot of my OpenGL ES view and save the result in a UIImage?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html)

Comment: what is your "snapshot method" exactly?

Comment: Used the same code form this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html